# Google colab does not display real time output while executing a cell

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

Normally when we run long execution commands (for eg. gmx) in a local linux command prompt, it displays the real time output during the execution. The output consists of number of steps, time remaining etc. [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7Cf2.png)

```
gmx mdrun -deffnm md_out -v
```

Above is the command itself that typically take 2 or 3 days to execute.

In the colab notebook [No output is displayed when the cell is executing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhTZl.png)

However, the output is displayed after the complete execution of the cell.